# merge 2 data.tables on partial match

Tags: r, regex, merge, data.table

I have data.table 1 like:

```
entidad                 municipio                   col1   
AGUASCALIENTES          Aguascalientes              5000
PUEBLA                  Jes�s Mar�a                 3000
VALLE                   Calvillo                    2000
JALISCO                 Pabell�n de Arteaga         1000
```

and data.table 2 like :

```
entidad                 municipio                   col2   
AGUASCALIENTES          Aguascalientes              16369
PUEBLA                  Jesus Maria                 1687
VALLE                   Calvillo                    916
JALISCO                 Pabellon de Arteaga         774
```

and I would like to perform a merge using the columns `entidad` and `municipio` like `merge(dt1, dt2, by = c('entidad', 'municipio'))` using a partial match on both columns or just in column `municipio`. However the problem is that data.table 1 has accents and the strange symbol `�` and thus the `municipio` column might differ on 3 different cases 1) by accent, 2) by symbol `�` or slightly different name (ej 'ciudad juarez' in dt1 and 'Juárez' in dt2). Since I am not very familiar with working with strings/character columns I was wondering if someone could help me in figuring out how to perform a merge in this case? the result that I would like to obtain is the following, from the previous example:

```
entidad                 municipio                   col1    col2
AGUASCALIENTES          Aguascalientes              5000    16369
PUEBLA                  Jesus Maria                 3000    1687
VALLE                   Calvillo                    2000    916
JALISCO                 Pabellon de Arteaga         1000    774
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `stringdist_join`-function from the [fuzzyjoin](/questions/tagged/fuzzyjoin)-package for that:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_join(d1, d2,
                by = c("entidad","municipio"),
                max_dist = 2,
                method = "lv")
```

this gives:

> ```
>        entidad.x         municipio.x col1      entidad.y         municipio.y  col2
> 1 AGUASCALIENTES      Aguascalientes 5000 AGUASCALIENTES      Aguascalientes 16369
> 2         PUEBLA         Jes�s Mar�a 3000         PUEBLA         Jesus Maria  1687
> 3          VALLE            Calvillo 2000          VALLE            Calvillo   916
> 4        JALISCO Pabell�n de Arteaga 1000        JALISCO Pabellon de Arteaga   774
> ```

After that you can use `dplyr::select` to retain the column you need.